# securitypolicyviolation event not fired for frame-ancestors directive

Tags: google-chrome, content-security-policy

I have the following file:

- `test.php`

```
<?php
$iframe = $_GET['iframe'];
if ($iframe) {
    header("Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: frame-ancestors 'none'; report-to csp-endpoint");
    header('Reporting-Endpoints: csp-endpoint="https://my-csp-endpoint.io"');
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener("securitypolicyviolation", (e) => {
                console.log(e.blockedURI);
                console.log(e.violatedDirective);
                console.log(e.originalPolicy);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?= $iframe ? 'hello!' : '<iframe src="/test.php?iframe=1"></iframe>' ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I have noticed that when the `frame-ancestors` directive is violated I get the following message in the Chrome console `[Report Only] Refused to frame 'https://32ca-2a02-b023-8012-cee0-f6f6-7d4f-28f-5c24.ngrok-free.app/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'".`, but after that no `securitypolicyviolation` event is fired and my reporting endpoint is not called at all.

Instead, if I change the CSP to something like `script-src 'none';`, then I get all, that is the error in the Chrome console, the event fired and the report sent to the requested URL.

Am I missing something or is there any bug in Chrome?